# Get the ID of the new activity saved from sending an email

Tags: apex, email

Is there a way to grab the activity Id's created from Messaging.sendEmail? I need to send the emails ID's out for processing.

Answer (score 0):

No. Emails are not sent until the transaction completes successfully, so those tasks won't exist yet. You could try to use an async method to get those new activities, but there's no easy way to identify which task goes with which email message.